# MongoDB: Which C Driver?

Tags: c, mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB and just found out that the MongoDB driver from the Ubuntu repositories I've been checking out is not the same as the official driver. My question is, what are their differences? I usually go with the official version of things unless there is a good reason not to, but I thought perhaps there is a reason that the alternate driver is included in the Ubuntu repositories and not the official one.

Comment: can you list the actual package name of the driver you are using from Ubuntu?  Then I can be a bit more specific than the general answer I was going to give.

Comment: libmongo-client0 is the package in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official MongoDB drivers are all to be found here:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Drivers

In addition, the official drivers all get moved under this root in Github:

https://github.com/mongodb/

That's the best way to get an up to date version of the driver.  In terms of MongoDB and Ubuntu/Debian in general - the official packages are available as described here (Ubuntu repos have very old versions):

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ubuntu+and+Debian+packages

EDIT:

The driver you mentioned is this one:

https://github.com/algernon/libmongo-client

The driver maintainer mentions that it has "slightly different" goals from the main driver, but not what those are specifically.  I think the main difference to look at is the level of maintenance and the frequency of updates:

https://github.com/algernon/libmongo-client/graphs/impact

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/graphs/impact

The official C driver is the basis for several of the other drivers, it is going to get a lot of developer time, quick bug fixes, immediate new feature support etc.  The libmongo-client driver has not seen any activity in several months - I am not criticising here, just making the observation.  For me, that alone would be a compelling reason why to use the official driver.

Comment: I didn't know about the 10gen repository, so thanks for that. But my question was about the differences between the two drivers, and if anyone has any clear advantage over the other.

Comment: I've added more to the answer, it's not a technical dissection of the pros/cons - I think you'd need to author of libmongo-client to do that

Comment: Looking at the level of maintenance and updates is a good observation. This answers my major concerns so I'm gonna accept it. Thank you.